# LT-spice-Simulation model for PV panel

Tags: voltage, power, current, resistors, diodes

I am totally new to LT-spice and i want to simulate a model for PV panel. i followed a youtube video as itas, but my circuit is not working. i have no idea about the errors it's showing. please help. I'll post snapshots below. the main circuit is about pv panel and sub circuit is a simulation model for single solalr cell.
[image: main circuit]

[image: sub circuit]

[image: the errors it is showing]

[image: error]

Comment: i solved the first error that says'can't find model definion R'.  please help with second error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first picture, you have two resistors, `Rs` and `Rp`. These are their *reference designators*. Their *values* are, by default, an undefined `R`, which needs to be changed into something that will evaluate to a numeric value. In your case, it looks like you defined some values, named after the reference designators, `Rp` and `Rs`, but you have not assigned them. For this, replace both relevant `R` into `{Rp}` and `{Rs}` (curly braces included). They should look something like this:

[image: etc]

The second error tells you about `F1`, which needs to take a current through a voltage source, and have a multiplying value attached to it. In your case, it looks like it needs to take the current through `Epv`, but I don't know what value you should assign to it. Try modifying `Fcell` to `Epv 1`, but you should really check your source for details about this.

However, it looks like you could use an introductory tutorial about how to use LTspice. It would be very recommended to follow one -- there are plenty on the net -- otherwise you'll just stumble after every little step you encounter. In other words, know the tool before using it, though nobody says you have to be a professional about it -- just enough to be able to use it without frustrations.

One of them might be loading the output with a voltage source (`Vpv` in your 2nd picture). That is meant to be the output of the panel.

Comment: it helped but a new error is showing now.

Comment: @eeegem You should have edited your post, not mine. :-) For the record, [this is OP's error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jJQi.jpg). Anyway, it looks like you added `Epv 1 1` (two `1`), instead of `Epv 1` (one `1`).

Comment: oops ^^''.. new here too ^^''   .Anyway i added one '1' only. I re-checked too.

Comment: @eeegem So is it working now? If yes, select the answer with the check mark (to the left of the answer). That lets anyone else in the future know that this problem has a solution.

Comment: yes. got it. Thank you so much! But can you tell the reason why changing Fcell to Epv 1 worked.

Comment: @eeegem If you look in the help (`F1`) under `LTspice > Circuit Elements > F. Current Dependent Current Source` you'll see the syntax: `Syntax: Fxxx n+ n- <Vnam> <gain>`. What you had (`Fcell`) was not a value, and whoever left it like that made the circuit unusable. The same for the other two resistors. You used `Epv 1 1`, but that's one more value than needed, so the parser complains about improper syntax. Now it's `Epv 1`, which is the equivalent of `<Vnam> <gain>`. As mentioned in the answer, be sure to verify the correct gain value, it may not be `1`, but some other value.